# Resuming Download in Android SDK Manager?

Tags: download, android

I was downloading packages using the Android SDK Manager. 
My internet connection got disconnected before the download finished and now the download does not resume and is stuck at 95% 
Is there no way to resume it?
Does it have to be stopped and restarted?

Comment: If it does not offer you a way to resume, then the partial file was not saved, which means you have to restart it.

Comment: Is there no way to pause/resume downloads in Android SDK manager?

Answer (score 0):

You can resume:
There are two hidden folders inside the SDK folder:

1. `.downloadIntermediates`
2. `.temp`

Inside the `.temp` you will see various PackageOperations.
It contains various completed as well as non-completed downloads.
The file which are not completed will be will be .asdownload

Copy/Move that file to the `.downloadIntermediates` folder.
And now try to download that specific file from the SDK Manager.
It will resume.

Answer (score -1):

the fact of downloading sdk is: you can resume the task if you still the sdk manager running this task need 31kib  for 13 min so if you stop without closing you can resume.

[image]

Comment: Your image isn't legible.  This seems more of a comment then an answer since you don't describe how to resume in any significant detail.  It might be the grammatical mistakes that exist, if those were fixed, I would consider reversing my vote.  *If somebody else does it for Ahmad I won't bother though.*